Nginx client_max_body_size not working in Pre-prod docker container, but in local it's working
I've an Nginx based Angular frontend app using docker, and I was getting 413(Payload Too Large) error when uploading a large file, I then tried to fix it by adding the following:
location / {
    client_max_body_size: 20M
}

And suddenly I stopped getting the error, when running my local docker container.
Now that I deployed the same changes in the prod, I'm still getting the same error.
I thought that if it's working in local it should work in the prepared as well, but that didn't, even though I'm using docker
What could be the reason, guys?
I'm not restarting the nginx server, as the Docker should apply a hot reload: Please refer here.
Please help.

You should ask this over on serverfault.com. You should include an overview of your production environment stack/setup too. It sounds like something upstream of your container in prod has a lower client_max_body_size - load balencers, ingress controllers etc (specific to your setup). Good luck! Voting to close / off topic
